# How to Use Blazor Editform without model object

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Iam generating dynamic form in blazor with EDitForm. I don't want to use any model, I just want to read fields by ID and I want to bind data to fields  when on EditContext changes. could you please suggest

Answer (score 4):

EditForm is mainly about validating input-- is it the right format (e-mail, phone number, password, etc.).

If you're not using a model, and you don't care about validating the input data, then you can just bind a field to any html control's `value`  For 70% of my inputs, I don't even bother with EditContext / EditForm / Models.

```
<input @bind="inputvalue" />

@code {
    string inputvalue;
}
```

By the way, the ID of an element is mostly irrelevant.  It's all done through binding and events.